# Add conv2D classifier to BERT

Tags: python, python-3.x, conv-neural-network, bert-language-model

I have dense neural network for BERT, How do I change that to Conv1D, maxpooling, and flatten, before connected to dense layer.

```
class BertBinaryClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dropout=0.1):
        super(BertBinaryClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        
    
    def forward(self, tokens, masks=None):
        _, pooled_output = self.bert(tokens, attention_mask=masks, output_all_encoded_layers=False)
        dropout_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        linear_output = self.linear(dropout_output)
        prediction = self.sigmoid(linear_output)
        return prediction
# Config setting
BATCH_SIZE = 4
EPOCHS = 5
```

Comment: This is not how a SO question should look like. You are not supposed to ask people to solve a problem for you, but show what solution you tried and what did not work. A short answer to your question: do not use the pooled output, but the states which are the first tuple member of what BERT returns. You can do the convolution and max-pooling in the standard way on them. Don't forget to apply the mask during maxpooling, so you do not include padding positions in the pooling.

Comment: Thanks I apologize for such dumb question. 
this is what I done
```
self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2D(512,3,kernel=5)
...
```
But it gives me error, Thank you for your short answer

Comment: Why do you want to put 2D conv? as the data is 1D